# How does one perform logistic regression analysis on a matrix

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am new to R and need to do a logistic regression on a list of phenotypes each with discrete 0 or 1 values using a list of single nucleotide polymorphisms (SNPs) as predictors (also discrete values of 0 or 1).
I've made a matrix using the two lists and now wish to do a univariate analysis covering every combination of every entity of the two groups

```
phenotypes <- colnames(regressioninput)[c(2:32, 47:56)]

SNPs01 <- colnames(regressioninput)[c(74:176)]

var1 = rep(phenotypes, length(SNPs01))

var1 = var1[order(var1)]

var2 = rep(SNPs01, length(phenotypes))

df = data.frame(a = var1, b = var2)


# first attempt at analysis
glm(phenotypes ~ SNPs01, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = regressioninput)


#second attempt
glm.formula <- mapply(var1, function(x) {paste(x, "~ var2 ")})
listglmOut<-lapply(glm.formula, function(f) glm(as.formula(f), family = binomial(link='logit'), data = df ))
```

error message reads variable lengths differ

Comment: Without see a sample of your data or even knowing which line generated the error, it is impossible to provide any meaningful help here.

Answer (score 0):

Again, it's hard to understand what you want without a sample of your data, so I can only guess that something like this will work:

```
set.seed(777)

dat <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), 100^2, replace = TRUE), 100, 100)
dat <- as.data.frame(dat)

gr1 <- names(dat)[1:20]
gr2 <- names(dat)[21:ncol(dat)]


res <- vector(mode = "list", length = 20*80)

for (i in seq_along(gr1)){
  for (j in seq_along(gr2)){
    ind <- 80*(i-1) + j
    res[[ind]] <- summary(glm(as.formula(paste0(gr1[i],'~',gr2[j])),
                    family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = dat))
  }
}
```